# (Python,Kivy) when i convert app to exe, popup doesn't work

Tags: python, user-interface, popup, kivy, exe

## Pop up and EXE issue

Hi guys I've got problem, whenever I open my Kivy Program via Python, a popup is actually showing up

[image: Progam ran in Python]

But when I convert it via Pyinstaller, it gives me an error:

[image: Program ran in exe]

How can I possibly fix this?

## Python Code:

```
import os
os.environ["KIVY_IMAGE"] = "pil, sdl2"

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup

Builder.load_file("kivy.kv")

class Rusure(Popup):
    pass

class Menu(Screen):
    def quit(self):
        Rusure().open()



class Settings(Screen):
    def bright (self,*args):
        self.brightness.text = "Brightness: {}".format(str(int(args[1])))

class Play(Screen):
    pass




class Sm(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.add_widget(Menu(name="menu"))
        self.add_widget(Settings(name="settings"))
        self.add_widget(Play(name="play"))

class GoodApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Sm()

GoodApp().run()
```

## Kivy Code:

```
#: import rit kivy.uix.screenmanager.RiseInTransition
#: import st kivy.uix.screenmanager.SlideTransition
#: import fot kivy.uix.screenmanager.FallOutTransition
#: import Factory kivy.factory.Factory
<Menu>:
  BoxLayout:
    padding: 100,100,100,100
    orientation: "vertical"
    Label:
      text: "Menu"
    BoxLayout:
      orientation: "horizontal"
      Button:
        text: "Play"
        background_normal: "Image.jpg"
        background_down: "ImageRel.jpg"
        color: 1,1,1,1
        on_press:
          root.manager.transition = rit()
          root.manager.current = "play"
      Button:
        text: "Settings"
        background_color: 0.9,1,1,1
        on_press:
          root.manager.transition = st()
          root.manager.current = "settings"
          root.manager.transition.direction = "up"
      Button:
        text: "Quit"
        background_color: 1,0.7,0,1
        on_press:
          root.quit()

<Settings>:
  brightness: brght
  BoxLayout:
    padding: 100,100,100,100
    orientation: "vertical"
    Label:
      text: "Settings"
    GridLayout:
      cols: 3
      Label:
        text: "Brightness"
      Slider:
        min: 0
        max: 10
        value: 5
        on_value: root.bright(*args)
      Label:
        id: brght
        text: "Change Value"
    Button:
      text: "Back"
      on_press:
        root.manager.transition = st()
        root.manager.current = "menu"
        root.manager.transition.direction = "down"

<Play>:
  BoxLayout:
    Label:
      text: "Welcome to the game!"
    Button:
      text: "Back"
      on_press:
        root.manager.transition = fot()
        root.manager.current = "menu"

<Rusure>:
  title: "Are you sure?"
  size_hint: 0.5,0.5
  auto_dismiss: False
  BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    Label:
      text: "Your progress will be lost"
    GridLayout:
      cols: 2
      Button:
        text: "Oh shit man!"
        on_press: root.dismiss()
      Button:
        text: "Cancel"
        on_press: root.dismiss()
```

I tried searching solution on the internet, but after 3 hours of searching I couldn't come up whith any answer.

Comment: It looks like the actual problem is related to font rendering, not the popup in particular. Specifically, something is wrong with PIL. Do you actually need to use PIL?

Comment: what did you include the `os` module in the spec file?